# Angular: Request HTTP GET with many params

Tags: angular, httprequest

I have a HTTP GET request with many params (~50 queryParams),

Currently I made this request

```
  get(contact?: Contact): Observable<response[]> {
    let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
    if (contact.company !== null) params = params.append('company', contact.company);
    if (contact.lastname !== null) params = params.set('lastname', contact.lastname);
    if (contact.firstname !== null) params = params.set('firstname', contact.firstname);


    return this.http.get<response[]>(`url/contact/`, {
      params: params,
    });
  }
```

How I can improve this request with 50 queryParams ?

Thank

Comment: I suggest you add all those params in a single object, I believe it would be easier.

Comment: You can use post method and send it in body. That seems like more feasible approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do following,

```
get(contact?: Contact): Observable<response[]> {

    let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

    Object.keys(contact).forEach(key => {
        if(contact[key]){          
           headers = headers.append(key, contact[key]);
        }
    });

    return this.http.get<response[]>(`url/contact/`, {
           params: params,
    });

}
```